# How \1 works in perl regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a string like (something is something).

```
$_ = "anna is ann";
if (/([a-zA-Z]+) is \1/) {
    print "matched\n";
}
```

I expected this not to work, but it works. Why?

Comment: One reason "Why?" is regex backtracking: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `print $1;` or `print $&;` - [`/([a-zA-Z]+) is \1/`](https://regex101.com/r/qUjhJQ/1) matches the `a is a` substring of `anna is ann`. If you want to restrict the match, you might want to anchor to the beginning and/or end of the string (or line, under [`/m`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)) with `^` resp. `$`, or use the word boundary [`\b`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#%5Cb%7B%7D,-%5Cb,-%5CB%7B%7D,-%5CB) if you want to match within a longer string. So:

[`/^([a-zA-Z]+) is \1$/`](https://regex101.com/r/j2axE3/1) will match `"anna is anna"` but not `"anna is ann"` or `"anna is anna "`.

[`/\b([a-zA-Z]+) is \1\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/7XKrru/1) will match `"x anna is anna y"` and `"sue-ann is ann-marie"` but not `"anna is ann"`, `"anna is anne"`, or `"anna is annabelle"`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"anchor to the beginning and/or end of the string (or line, under `/m`) with `^` resp. `$`"* What is the abbreviation `resp.`?

Comment: @Borodin I meant ["resp." = "respectively"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resp), although in English I guess "... with `^` or `$`, respectively" may be better; I may have used it too much [like](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=de-en&query=bzw) the German "[bzw.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bzw.)".

Answer (score 3):

It matches 6 chars starting at pos 3 (`a is a`). Perhaps you should have used

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+) is \1\z/
```

---

1. Starting a pos 0.

   1. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 4 chars at pos 0.

      1. `is`  matches 4 chars at pos 4.
      2. `\1` doesn't match at pos 8: Backtrack.
   2. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 3 chars at pos 0.

      1. `is`  doesn't match at pos 3: Backtrack.
   3. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 2 chars at pos 0.

      1. `is`  doesn't match at pos 2: Backtrack.
   4. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 1 chars at pos 0.

      1. `is`  doesn't match at pos 1: Backtrack.
2. Starting a pos 1.

   1. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 3 chars at pos 1.

      1. `is`  matches 4 chars at pos 4.
      2. `\1` doesn't match at pos 8: Backtrack.
   2. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 2 chars at pos 1.

      1. `is`  doesn't match at pos 3: Backtrack.
   3. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 1 chars at pos 1.

      1. `is`  doesn't match at pos 2: Backtrack.
3. Starting a pos 2.

   1. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 2 chars at pos 2.

      1. `is`  matches 4 chars at pos 4.
      2. `\1` doesn't match at pos 8: Backtrack.
   2. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 1 chars at pos 2.

      1. `is`  doesn't match at pos 3: Backtrack.
4. Starting a pos 3.

   1. `[a-zA-Z]+` matches 1 char at pos 3.

      1. `is`  matches 4 chars at pos 4.
      2. `\1` matches 1 char at pos 8.
      3. Match! (6 chars starting at pos 3)